# Go to method declaration

Tags: sublimetext

Is it possible to got to PHP method declaration through method call in Sublime Text?

```php
// pressing some keys combination should navigate me
// to the method declaration. If it's defined in some other file,
// the file should be opened.
$foo->doSomething();
```

Comment: It's possible through a plugin, but it's language specific.  What language do you want it for?

Comment: Just the question that I was going to ask.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Update (June 2016):** [@Erik255's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089862/584676) is better now that Sublime Text 3 is out. Please upvote his. Since this is currently the accepted answer, these are the steps repeated:

1. Use "File > Open Folder" or "Project > Add folder to project" (you may need to create a project first)
2. <kbd>F12</kbd> will jump to any symbol in the project

---

*Original answer:*

As of Sublime Text 2, you can use Goto anything (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

*(searches only within the current page)*

---

Comment: Did you mean sublime text 3? This doesn't seem to work in my sublime?

Comment: It does not seem to work to look for definitions of methods from other files in the same project folder, only from the same file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. [The other answer by @ogrisel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21218979/434961) seems to be a working solution.

Comment: Actually Go To Anything is Ctrl-P, which is supposed to search across files, but doesn't seem to work for me. Ctrl-R is Go To Symbol, which I find more useful for finding functions/declarations within the current file.

Comment: You need to type in the function name after the @ symbol and it will work.  Don't delete the @ symbol when the dialog pops up after Ctrl + R

Comment: After using [F12] to jump to the symbol, you can use [Alt]+[-] to go back.

Comment: Yep - `Alt`+`-` is great because it jumps to your previous cursor position regardless of how you got there.

Answer (score 111):

Sublime 3 is the answer! It has a goto_definition function build in which works fine as long as you have a project with your source folder added (so that they can get indexed). 
I use it with scala+lift, PHP, Python.

Per default it is bound to <kbd>F12</kbd> and without project setup it searches only in the actual file.

It was the missing feature to leave Eclipse and Netbeans.

Comment: how do you mean *as long as you have your source folder added*? I'm working on a javascript project that uses mapbox, which in turn uses [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).. if i were to download leaflet where do i put it to jump to the leaflet method definitions?

Comment: `File` -> `Open Folder`  and open your code root folder. Everything inside will be indexed.

Comment: `File` -> `Open Folder` is not an option under OSX ST3 (at least in build 3059)

Comment: @watsonic You can just select a folder in the standard open dialog.

Comment: you can also simply drag & drop your folder inside sublime and it will be opened in the same way

Comment: How to bound this functionality to `CTRL+LMB`? I like to jump by clicking symbols in code when I get along with libraries I downloaded.

Comment: Goto definition does not even work within the same php file. Maybe ST3 does not like PHP?

Answer (score 14):

There is a CTags package for Sublime Text that makes it possible to use a project level <del>.ctags</del> `.tags` index file to jump to the definition of the symbol under the cursor by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> twice: https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags

Comment: Please note that Sublime Text's Ctags plugin wants the file to be called **.tags** by default, but this can be altered in the plugin settings

Answer (score 3):

There is a great plugin called [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel) with the following features:

- Jump to Symbol Definition - Jump to the file and line of the definition of a symbol.
- Imports autocomplete - Shows autocomplete with the available modules/symbols in real time.
- Function Call tooltips - Displays information in the status bar about the working function.

Comment: Note that this plugin is language specific.

Answer (score 1):

For Python,

I added the project to sublime.

I press `CTRL+R` and then start typing the name of my function. The cursor then points to the beginning of function definition.

Hope this helps.